# XAML Designer Error - Intellisense Missing

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, intellisense, windows-10

I am Experiencing the following error with:
- Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate Update 1 (Same with Update 3)
- Windows 10 TP Build 9860
- Windows Store Apps Only (No error with a WPF Desktop Application).

Error Decription:
- UI XAML Designer doesn't work (see attached exception)
- Intellisense in the XAML file doesn't work (no suggestion showed up).

```
System.Exception
Install failed. Please contact your software vendor.

Deployment Register operation with target volume C: on Package App.aa5630c6a.a99c1.a41a2.aaba0.ac20dd792d3d9_1.0.0.0_x86_NorthAmerica_8wekyb3d8bbwe from:  (C:\Users\Diego\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Designer\ShadowCache\hwvetbdr.ucs\pfhjajzj.4bs\AppXManifest.xml)  failed with error 0x80070002. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160 for help diagnosing app deployment issues.
   at Microsoft.Expression.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateDesignerProcess(String applicationPath, String clientPort, Uri hostUri, IDictionary environmentVariables, Int32& processId, Object& processData)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.ProcessIsolationDomain..ctor(ProcessDomainFactory factory, IIsolationBoundary boundary, AppDomainSetup appDomainInfo, FrameworkName targetFramework, String identifier, String baseDirectory)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Primitives.ProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary boundary)
   at Microsoft.Expression.HostUtility.Platform.AppContainerProcessDomainFactory.CreateIsolationDomain(IIsolationBoundary boundary)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Primitives.IsolationBoundary.CreateInstance[T](Type type)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolatedObjectFactory.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExpressionHost.Services.VSIsolationService.CreateObjectFactory(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, IObjectCatalog catalog)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolationService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.IsolatedDesignerService.CreateLease(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, CancellationToken cancelToken, DesignerServiceEntry& entry)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.InvokeWithCulture[T](CultureInfo culture, Func`2 func, CancellationToken cancelToken)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.IsolatedTaskScheduler.<>c__DisplayClassa`1.<StartTask>b__6()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

[image: Exception]

Uninstalling and re-installing didn't fix it.
Has anyone experienced it ?

Edit:
Also property tab is blank for every XAML Control

Comment: Win10 is a technical preview to show the new UI (Startmenu, virtual desktops), it is not stable and should not be used for coding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows 10 is currently a technical preview and is not meant for you to develop up on, you need o wait for the Windows 10 Developer Preview so that you can start coding on Windows 10 (which will probably come out near the BUILD 2015 event in my opinion).

As they say here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/dn798751.aspx?ocid=wc-mscom-wol

"Windows 10 Technical Preview for Enterprise is an early look at some of the features and functionality in store for Windows 10, the next version of the Windows client operating system. This page offers resources to help you explore Technical Preview for Enterprise, assess the compatibility of your applications, and test the new in-place upgrade process."

From what i understand from this, it is mainly for you to test your apps and company apps on the OS to see if your company will be able to migrate on this or not and not for your to start coding.

Good Luck!

EDIT:
Went you look at the TechNet forum: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?category=WinPreview2014
you can see that they are mainly looking a bugs with the OS and not about how to develop apps.